# Reading file into arraylist

Tags: java

I am trying to read a file into an arraylist whose data is as follows:

```
name: a 
year: 1990
subjects: phy, chem,math, eng
name :b
year : 1996
subjects: eng,chem
```

These are not CSV, but every new data and its value are on next line.

I need a separate method in `main` to read data and store in a list using the `Info` class. I need help with that.

I have made getters, setters and to string method in Info class.

```
    public Info (String name, int year, List<String> sub) {
        this.name = name;
        this.year = year;
        this.sub = sub;
    }
```

Comment: your question is not clear. Do you need help with how could you read a file? Provide your code where you are reading a file.

Answer (score 1):

I assumed that your input file looks like... (Maybe there are some typos in your post.)

> name: a year: 1990 subjects: phy,chem,math,eng
>   name: b year: 1996 subjects: eng,chem

And I also assumed that you already have a class (says `Info`) as follows to store the content of each line:

```
class Info {
    private String name;
    private int year;
    private List<String> sub;

    //constructors
    //general getters and setters
    //toString()
}
```

Then you can read the file into `List<Info>` by following approach:

**Code snippet**

```
List<Info> infoList = new ArrayList<>();
for (String line : Files.readAllLines(yourFilepath, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
    String[] tokens = line.split(" ");
    infoList.add(new Info(tokens[1],
                          Integer.valueOf(tokens[3]), 
                          Arrays.asList(tokens[5].split(","))));

    /* this is equal to above if there is no constructor with fields
    Info info = new Info();
    info.setName(tokens[1]);
    info.setYear(Integer.valueOf(tokens[3]));
    info.setSub(Arrays.asList(tokens[5].split(",")));
    infoList.add(info);
    */
}
System.out.println(infoList.toString());
```

**Console output**

> [Info [name=a, year=1990, sub=[phy, chem, math, eng]], Info [name=b, year=1996, sub=[eng, chem]]]

***UPDATE***
If you are using `Scanner`, you can get the same result:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(yourFilename));
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String[] tokens = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
    infoList.add(new Info(tokens[1],
                          Integer.valueOf(tokens[3]), 
                          Arrays.asList(tokens[5].split(","))));
}
System.out.println(infoList.toString());
```

Comment: @Rishika Please refer to Reading a .txt file using Scanner class in Java. I have updated my solution to add the approach, please check!

Comment: I my opinion, splitting by " " not correct.  `"name :b".split(" ")` return [name][:b]. Use split(":")

Comment: @Elgin Yes! But I think that `name :b` is a typo, it is supposed to be `name: b`, just like other fields. :)

Comment: Maybe it is a typo, but my version will work anyway. As an additional, you can use trim() to remove any leading and trailing whitespace

Comment: @Elgin Thanks for your input! Because the questioner didn't clearly specify the format of file content. If each line looks like **name: a year: 1990 subjects: phy,chem,math,eng**, then additional processing is required by using `split(":")`.